# 3.3V LDO alternative using SOC analog output?

Tags: power-supply, emitter-follower

I want to build a little adapter board to connect an existing PSOC prototyping board (CY8CKIT-059) to QIIC connector (which is just I2C using JST 4-pin connectors).   The QIIC standard calls for 3.3V power, but my board doesn't have that, just the USB VBUS derrived 5 Volts.

Rather than drop an LDO on my adapter, I thought I might take advantage of a spare opamp on the PSOC, but the output pins are limited to about 25 mA, I want to go higher than that.   Dusting off mental cobwebs, I recall building an emitter follower with a 2N2222.  (Does that part date me?)   [Here's the idea:](https://easyeda.com/editor#mode=sim,id=d85f0d603653434ca60f058f0e7183f4)

[image: emitter follower circuit]

Would a using a MOSFET here instead of a bipolar have any advantage?

I've not done any surface mount before, but with JLCPCB's assembly service, it seems like time to give it a try.   Is there a way for me to look up something similar the old through-hole transistor in a SMD package.

Comment: You can go to any of the leading component vendors and easily find a 2n2222 in an SMT package. Is that really your question?

Comment: Well, sort of.   I'm hoping to do this with JLCPCB smd assembly.   [Their part search doesn't show anything when I ask for 2N2222.](https://jlcpcb.com/parts/componentSearch?searchTxt=2n2222)

Comment: LDO’s work fine with NPN’s given the headroom. Try PN2222A

Comment: Thanks.   I thought uC adjustable voltage this setup would give me is better than with an LDO.

Comment: I found a part called a MMBT2222A on the JLCPCB parts list.   Still wondering if a MOSFET would have any advantage.

Comment: How come XMM3 shows 33uA yet clearly there must be 165 mA flowing in R_LOAD? C1 might be a step too far and turn the circuit into an oscillator.

Comment: @andyaka I think its because SW1 is shown in the open state.  I've simulated with that switch both open and closed.   The simulation showed no persistant oscillations with SW1 in either position. C1 is acting as a output filter cap.   Larger => more stable, but I just chose a for-example value.

Comment: Well until you definitely get to the bottom of things, there's no point contemplating this or that change. I mean you propose a circuit that appears to be "faulty" and ask about stuff and, that makes it tricky to answer.

Comment: With SW1 closed, XMM3 shows 164mA, pretty much as you expected.   I think you can access the simulation online at https://easyeda.com/editor#mode=sim,id=d85f0d603653434ca60f058f0e7183f4